# How can I make a directive replace everything inside a DIV including the DIV itself?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following directive call:

```
<div data-my-activity></div>
```

Here's the directive:

```
app.directive('myActivity', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div class='activity-mask' data-ng-show='fetching.length > 0' >" +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li data-ng-repeat='activity in fetching'>{{ activity }}</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='activity-mask' data-ng-show='loading.length > 0' >" +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li data-ng-repeat='activity in loading'>{{ activity }}</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>"
    };
});
```

When I use this directive it gives me:

```
<div data-my-activity="">
   <div class="activity-mask ng-hide" 
        data-ng-show="fetching.length &gt; 0">
      <ul><!-- ngRepeat: activity in fetching --></ul>
   </div>
   <div class="activity-mask ng-hide" 
        data-ng-show="loading.length &gt; 0">
      <ul><!-- ngRepeat: activity in loading --></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can make this give me the following if fetching.length and loading.length are both equal to 0 ?

```
<div style="display:none">
   <div class="activity-mask ng-hide" 
        data-ng-show="fetching.length &gt; 0">
      <ul><!-- ngRepeat: activity in fetching --></ul>
   </div>
   <div class="activity-mask ng-hide" 
        data-ng-show="loading.length &gt; 0">
      <ul><!-- ngRepeat: activity in loading --></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the following if fetching.length or loading.length are not equal to 0 ?

```
<div style="display:block">>
   <div class="activity-mask ng-hide" 
        data-ng-show="fetching.length &gt; 0">
      <ul><!-- ngRepeat: activity in fetching --></ul>
   </div>
   <div class="activity-mask ng-hide" 
        data-ng-show="loading.length &gt; 0">
      <ul><!-- ngRepeat: activity in loading --></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I tried the proposed answer but it gives me problems with the quote marks as I have three levels of quotes on the one line.

```
app.directive('myActivity', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div ng-style="{display: loading.length > 0 || fetching.length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none'}">
        "<ul>" +
        "<li data-ng-repeat='activity in fetching'>{{ activity }}</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='activity-mask' data-ng-show='loading.length > 0' >" +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li data-ng-repeat='activity in loading'>{{ activity }}</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pass the option

```
replace: true
```

into the directive, and the template specified will replace all of the html of the element, including the element itself

```
app.directive('myActivity', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    template: "..."
  };
});
```

Edit: To then show/hide the contents dynamically, you should be able to set display:none template using ngStyle

```
template: '<div ng-style="{display: loading.length > 0 || fetching.length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none'}">....';
```

Alternatively, you could do an ngIf you don't actually need the elements in the DOM

```
template: '<div ng-if="loading.length > 0 || fetching.length > 0">....';
```

Edit: I had ngShow where I actually meant ngIf

Comment: Thanks but how could I do that and also change the display of the outer DIV between none and block depending on if either of the arrays have a length?

Comment: I tried to do what you said but I have problems as I have a " and then a " and then a ' all inside of one another. Can you have a look at my question Update section.  Let me know what you think is the solution and if I am on the right track. Thanks

Comment: Can you make a plunkr to show your issue: it's hard to debug on here.

Comment: One thing that might help is always using single quotes for JS strings, and then using double quotes inside them for HTML attributes. Say `'template': '<a href="...."'`

Comment: Hello Michal. I fixed the problem. It was saying: Template for directive 'myActivity' must have exactly one root element. I fixed this now and also the quotes so it's working okay. Thanks

Comment: @MichalCharemza I have never heard of `replace`, do you mean [`transclude`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)?

Comment: @Asok I think I do mean replace, as in, the template should replace not just the contents of the element, but the element itself. Described at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile (with a section that describes transclude after it)

Comment: @MichalCharemza Okay nice, I hadn't seen `replace` before and when trying to search I didn't get far. Thanks for the link.